# splitting a path with python

Tags: python, split, urlparse

I am trying to get cut everything off after the last decimal and add "html" to the end

html

```
<a href="http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.1.ceb">http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.1.ceb</a>
```

current code returns "gen.1.ceb"

```
name = urlparse.urlparse(url).path.split('/')[-1]
```

I want name to get "gen.1.html"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like that:

```
filename = urlparse.urlparse(url).path.split('/')[-1]  # get file name
name = filename.rsplit('.', 1)[0] + '.html'  # change the extension
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
re.sub(r'\.[A-Za-z]+$','.html',url)
```